# Variable attribute names in jade

Tags: javascript, pug

Is it possible to have a variable attribute name in jade?  I want to create a mixin that will have different name for the attributes:

```
mixin button_post(test)
    button(
            #{test.name}='#{test.value}'
    )
```

Would also be nice if this could be done in a loop:

```
mixin button_post()
    button(
        each key, value in {one: 'one', two: 'two', three: 'three'}
            #{key}='#{value}'
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this one out:

```
mixin test_button(button_text, test)
    each value, key in test
        - attributes[key] = value
    button&(attributes) !{button_text}

+test_button('test', {test: 'test', test2: 'test2'})
```

Results in:

```
<button test="test" test2="test2">test</button>
```

Comment: Hmm, this just outputs <button attributes="attributes">test</button> for me. Could it be a change in how Jade renders since this question was answered?

Comment: But it works if I changed the last row to the following!   button&attributes(attributes) !{button_text}